# Excel Button to Update Cell from Value List

Tags: excel, vba, office365, ms-office, spreadsheet

**Context:** I'm making a spreadsheet to track various projects. There is a master worksheet with all the data for each project and other worksheets that only show the data relevant to certain tasks via filters and lookups. Each task has a column on the master worksheet to track the status. Since no data is actually stored on the task worksheets, I wanted a way to update the status column for a task on the master worksheet from one of the task worksheets.

**Question:** How do I make a button or macro that 1) updates the value of a cell on another sheet and 2) cycles through a set list of values? (*e.g. Clicking once changes the value to "Not Done", second time changes it to "In Progress", third time changes it to "Done", and fourth time cycles back and changes it to "Not Done"*)

**Example:**

```
Master Worksheet
+----+------+------+----------+
| ID | Col1 | Col2 | Status   |
+----+------+------+----------+
|0001| Foo  | Bar  | Done     |
|0002| Bar  | Foo  | Not Done |
+----+------+------+----------+

Task Worksheet
+----+------+----------+--------+
| ID | Col2 | Status   | Update |
+----+------+----------+--------+
|0002| Foo  | Not Done | Button |
+----+------+----------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to find the range of your Master Worksheet Table. Then parse `ID`s to find your task. Once the task is found, get the status. Compare the status to an array to get your next Value, then set it.

If it's formatted as an excel table, try something like this. Note that there may be bugs as I don't have time to test it right now:

```
Sub example()
    ' Open the file
    Set wbMaster = Workbooks.Open("Master.xlsm")
    
    ' Get Sheet
    Set oSheet = wbMaster.Worksheets("My Sheet")

    ' Get Table
    Set loTable = oSheet.Table("Master Table")
    
    ' Get the header indexes
    lHeaderIndex_ID = loTable.ListColumns("ID").Index
    lHeaderIndex_Status = loTable.ListColumns("Status").Index
    
    ' Find where your ID is
    sMyID = "0002"
    lRowIndex = Application.Match(sMyID, loTable.ListColumns(lHeaderIndex_ID).DataBodyRange, 0)
    
    ' Get your status
    If Not lRowIndex Is Nothing Then
        Status = loTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(lRowIndex, lHeaderIndex_Status).Value
    Else
        Status = vbNullString
    End If
    
    ' Get your next status
    Dim aStatus(0 To 2) As Variant
    aStatus(0) = "Not Done"
    aStatus(1) = "In Progress"
    aStatus(2) = "Done"
    
    lStatusNumber = Application.Match(Status, aStatus, 2) + 1
    sNewStatus = aStatus(lStatusNumber Mod 3)
    
    ' Set your status
    If Not lRowIndex Is Nothing Then ' The row was found
        loTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(lRowIndex, lHeaderIndex_Status).Value = sNewStatus
    Else ' Add a new row
        Set rNewRow = loTable.ListRows.Add
        rNewRow.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, lHeaderIndex_ID).Value = sMyID
        rNewRow.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, lHeaderIndex_Status).Value = sNewStatus
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help. I'll use this as a starting point and let you know if it works out.

Comment: @Ethameshep No problem. Please report back any changes you make.